# Default value of tabBarController.selectedViewController?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, default-value

In my iOS app I have a tabBarController with a few navigationControllers. In applicationDidFinishLaunching `tabBarController.selectedViewController` is `null`. This is after I assign the navigationControllers to the tabBar's tabBarItems.

What is an appropriate default value for `tabBarController.selectedViewController`?

Perhaps it can be set to the first navigationController. Might need to be careful of the app launching from the background (in which case the user might not have left off at the first navigationController).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation for [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), under `selectedViewController`:

> This view controller is the one whose custom view is currently
>   displayed by the tab bar interface. The specified view controller must
>   be in the viewControllers array. Assigning a new view controller to
>   this property changes the currently displayed view and also selects an
>   appropriate tab in the tab bar. Changing the view controller also
>   updates the selectedIndex property accordingly. ***The default value of
>   this property is nil.***